# Disable panel sidebar item - OpenLayers, from a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, openlayers, sidebar

I'm using the example https://turbo87.github.io/sidebar-v2/examples/ however, the sidebar with OpenLayers. See that in the example, we have a nopanel id that initializes disabled

[CODE HTML]

```
<div class="sidebar-tabs">
    <ul role="tablist">
       <li class="disabled"><a href="#messages" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
    </ul>          
</div>
```

I would like to initialize this enabled item:

```
<li><a href="#messages" role="tab"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
```

however, I would like to disable it through a function, from the click of another button. However, I am not succeeding.

[JS]

```
document.getElementById("messages").classList.add("disabled");
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I got what I needed, disabled a panel item. Consider the id="messages":

```
 document.getElementById("messages").parentNode.classList.add("disabled");
```

To enable it again:

```
document.getElementById("messages").parentNode.classList.remove("disabled");
```